# Spring Boot @Schedular not running after first execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have written this scheduled task in my SpringBoot app:

```
@Component
public class TestTaskScheduler {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Run again and again and again");
    }
}
```

This runs first time, but not subsequently.

Comment: have you added `@EnableScheduling` to the application or configuration?

Comment: Problem solved as per my answer. Just wanted to share so that it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was running another "heavy" scheduled task in the same application (it was initially created for testing my business logic and then I forgot to remove that). When I removed the other task, the issue got resolved. (It seems that another task was using most of the resources so the current task was waiting for long time to be scheduled again.)

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, if you don't provide thread pool size configuration for scheduler, scheduled tasks run on the same thread. So if there is one scheduled task that say, is resource/time consuming, other scheduled tasks wont run.

Answer (score 0):

Try add @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L * 60 * 60) .

This means that it will run every 60 minutes. You can determine the working time by changing the last digit.